# Working with arbitrary inequalities and checking which, if any, are satisfied

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Given a non-negative integer n and an arbitrary set of inequalities that are user-defined (in say an external text file), I want to determine whether n satisfies any inequality, and if so, which one(s).

---

Here is a points list.

```
n = 0: 1
n < 5: 5
n = 5: 10
```

If you draw a number n that's equal to 5, you get 10 points.
If n less than 5, you get 5 points.
If n is 0, you get 1 point.

---

The stuff left of the colon is the "condition", while the stuff on the right is the "value".
All entries will be of the form:

```
n1 op n2: val
```

In this system, equality takes precedence over inequality, so the order that they appear in will not matter in the end. The inputs are non-negative integers, though intermediary and results may not be non-negative. The results may not even be numbers (eg: could be strings). I have designed it so that will only accept the most basic inequalities, to make it easier for writing a parser (and to see whether this idea is feasible)

My program has two components:

1. a parser that will read structured input and build a data structure to store the conditions and their associated results.
2. a function that will take an argument (a non-negative integer) and return the result (or, as in the example, the number of points I receive)

If the list was hardcoded, that is an easy task: just use a case-when or if-else block and I'm done. But the problem isn't as easy as that.

Recall the list at the top. It can contain an arbitrary number of (in)equalities. Perhaps there's only 3 like above. Maybe there are none, or maybe there are 10, 20, 50, or even 1000000. Essentially, you can have m inequalities, for m >= 0

Given a number n and a data structure containing an arbitrary number of conditions and results, I want to be able to determine whether it satisfies any of the conditions and return the associated value. So as with the example above, if I pass in 5, the function will return 10.

They condition/value pairs are not unique in their raw form. You may have multiple instances of the same (in)equality but with different values. eg:

```
n = 0: 10
n = 0: 1000
n > 0: n
```

Notice the last entry: if n is greater than 0, then it is just whatever you got.

If multiple inequalities are satisfied (eg: n > 5, n > 6, n > 7), all of them should be returned. If that is not possible to do efficiently, I can return just the first one that satisfied it and ignore the rest. But I would like to be able to retrieve the entire list.

---

I've been thinking about this for a while and I'm thinking I should use two hash tables: the first one will store the equalities, while the second will store the inequalities.

Equality is easy enough to handle: Just grab the condition as a key and have a list of values. Then I can quickly check whether n is in the hash and grab the appropriate value.

However, for inequality, I am not sure how it will work. Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this problem in as little computational steps as possible? It's clear that I can easily accomplish this in O(n) time: just run it through each (in)equality one by one. But what happens if this checking is done in real-time? (eg: updated constantly)

For example, it is pretty clear that if I have 100 inequalities and 99 of them check for values > 100 while the other one checks for value <= 100, I shouldn't have to bother checking those 99 inequalities when I pass in 47.

You may use any data structure to store the data. The parser itself is not included in the calculation because that will be pre-processed and only needs to be done once, but if it may be problematic if it takes too long to parse the data.

Since I am using Ruby, I likely have more flexible options when it comes to "messing around" with the data and how it will be interpreted.

Comment: So much text. Is it possible to summarize your question more succinctly?

Comment: Added a summary, although I'm not sure if it captures every detail. I only included the part I am having trouble with (inequalities)

Comment: All three answers are good and provide different ways of looking at it but I can only choose one lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class RuleSet
  Rule = Struct.new(:op1,:op,:op2,:result) do
    def <=>(r2)
      # Op of "=" sorts before others
      [op=="=" ? 0 : 1, op2.to_i] <=> [r2.op=="=" ? 0 : 1, r2.op2.to_i]
    end
    def matches(n)
      @op2i ||= op2.to_i
      case op
        when "=" then n == @op2i
        when "<" then n  < @op2i
        when ">" then n  > @op2i
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(text)
    @rules = text.each_line.map do |line|
      Rule.new *line.split(/[\s:]+/)
    end.sort
  end

  def value_for( n )
    if rule = @rules.find{ |r| r.matches(n) }
      rule.result=="n" ? n : rule.result.to_i
    end
  end
end

set = RuleSet.new( DATA.read )
-1.upto(8) do |n|
  puts "%2i => %s" % [ n, set.value_for(n).inspect ]
end

#=> -1 => 5
#=>  0 => 1
#=>  1 => 5
#=>  2 => 5
#=>  3 => 5
#=>  4 => 5
#=>  5 => 10
#=>  6 => nil
#=>  7 => 7
#=>  8 => nil

__END__
n = 0: 1
n < 5: 5
n = 5: 10
n = 7: n
```

Comment: I like how it works. Can the parser be modified so that when it reads duplicate conditions with different results, it will be a list? Like if I have have two n = 0 entries, one returns 3 and the other returns 5, then I will get [3, 5]

Comment: @Keikoku Sure it can. Change `find` to `select` and modify the logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not spending a lot of time on your problem, but here's my quick thought:

Since the `points list` is always in the format `n1 op n2: val`, I'd just model the points as an array of hashes.

So first step is to parse the input point list into the data structure, an array of hashes.
Each hash would have values n1, op, n2, value

Then, for each data input you run through all of the hashes (all of the points) and handle each (determining if it matches to the input data or not).

**Some tricks of the trade**

Spend time in your parser handling bad input. Eg

```
n < = 1000  # no colon
n < : 1000  # missing n2
x < 2 : 10  # n1, n2 and val are either number or "n"
n           # too short, missing :, n2, val
n < 1 : 10x # val is not a number and is not "n"
```

etc

Also politely handle non-numeric input data

**Added**

Re: n1 doesn't matter. Be careful, this could be a trick. Why wouldn't

```
5 < n : 30
```

be a valid points list item?

Re: multiple arrays of hashes, one array per operator, one hash per point list item -- sure that's fine. Since each op is handled in a specific way, handling the operators one by one is fine. But....ordering then becomes an issue:

Since you want multiple results returned from multiple matching point list items, you need to maintain the overall order of them. Thus I think one array of all the point lists would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: "data input" refers to the number that I pass into the function right? n1 isn't too important; it is like a placeholder so users know what it means. The only important information is the operator and n2. On that note, what if I had separate hashes for each operator? for example, one of my array of hashes represents the ">" operator, so I just have to grab all of the values that satisfy (input) > (key)

Comment: Re: data input: right. Re n1: What if a point list is `5 < n: 100` ??

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the input lines and separate them into predicate/result pairs and build a hash of callable procedures (using `eval` - oh noes!).  The "check" function can iterate through each predicate and return the associated result when one is true:

```ruby
class PointChecker
  def initialize(input)
    @predicates = Hash[input.split(/\r?\n/).map do |line|
      parts = line.split(/\s*:\s*/)
      [Proc.new {|n| eval(parts[0].sub(/=/,'=='))}, parts[1].to_i]
    end]
  end
  def check(n)
    @predicates.map { |p,r| [p.call(n) ? r : nil] }.compact
  end
end
```

Here is sample usage:

```ruby
p = PointChecker.new <<__HERE__
  n = 0: 1
  n = 1: 2
  n < 5: 5
  n = 5: 10
__HERE__
p.check(0) # => [1, 5] 
p.check(1) # => [2, 5] 
p.check(2) # => [5] 
p.check(5) # => [10] 
p.check(6) # => []
```

Of course, there are many issues with this implementation.  I'm just offering a proof-of-concept.  Depending on the scope of your application you might want to build a proper parser and runtime (instead of using `eval`), handle input more generally/gracefully, etc.